# Python: force to release objects from memory in for-loop (or remove caches)

Tags: python, memory

I'm doing a little research about Python object memory sizes. I encounter a problem with memory management (recycling pool).

We declare a class A and a function to create different attribute sizes of objects:

```py
from sys import getsizeof

class A:
    def __init__(self, mydict):
        for k, v in mydict.items():
            # set attr dynamically
            setattr(self, k, v)
        pass

def get_object_dict(count):
    # create an object from a dict (key-value pairs for attributes)
    kv_pairs = dict([(f'k{i}', i) for i in range(count)])
    o = A(kv_pairs)
    # inspect the attribute dict
    d = o.__dict__
    print(
        f'attr: {count:3}  || ',
        f'o id: {id(o)}  || ', 
        f'__dict__ id: {id(d)}, size: {getsizeof(d):4}, len: {len(d):3}', 
    )
    return d
```

for example

```py
# a object with 3 attributes
obj = get_object_dict(3)
print(obj)
```

```
attr:   3  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4366370560, size:  104, len:   3
{'k0': 0, 'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}
```

Now I tried to inspect objects with different attribute sizes for a range:

```py
for i in range(20):
    get_object_dict(i)
```

```
attr:   0  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  104, len:   0
attr:   1  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  104, len:   1
attr:   2  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  104, len:   2
attr:   3  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  104, len:   3
attr:   4  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  104, len:   4
attr:   5  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  104, len:   5
attr:   6  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  144, len:   6
attr:   7  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  144, len:   7
attr:   8  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  144, len:   8
attr:   9  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  144, len:   9
attr:  10  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  144, len:  10
attr:  11  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  232, len:  11
attr:  12  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  232, len:  12
attr:  13  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  232, len:  13
attr:  14  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  232, len:  14
attr:  15  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  232, len:  15
attr:  16  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  232, len:  16
attr:  17  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  232, len:  17
attr:  18  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  232, len:  18
attr:  19  ||  o id: 4362516656  ||  __dict__ id: 4366171648, size:  232, len:  19
```

The `getsizeof(o.__dict__)` are increasing from 104 to 232 for different attribute sizes. How about I reverse the loop range?

```py
for i in reversed(range(20)):
    get_object_dict(i)
```

```
attr:  19  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:  19
attr:  18  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:  18
attr:  17  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:  17
attr:  16  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:  16
attr:  15  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:  15
attr:  14  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:  14
attr:  13  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:  13
attr:  12  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:  12
attr:  11  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:  11
attr:  10  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:  10
attr:   9  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:   9
attr:   8  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:   8
attr:   7  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:   7
attr:   6  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:   6
attr:   5  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:   5
attr:   4  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:   4
attr:   3  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:   3
attr:   2  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:   2
attr:   1  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4365799872, size:  232, len:   1
attr:   0  ||  o id: 4362505424  ||  __dict__ id: 4366123136, size:  232, len:   0
```

Surprisingly, the `getsizeof(o.__dict__)` are always 232.

I notice that the object ids and `__dict__` ids are the same. I think that was about recycling objects with a pool. So I tried to call `gc.collect()` to release objects through Python's garbage collection.

```py
import gc
for i in reversed(range(20)):
    get_object_dict(i)
    gc.collect()
```

```
attr:  19  ||  o id: 4362544336  ||  __dict__ id: 4366166656, size:  232, len:  19
attr:  18  ||  o id: 4362544384  ||  __dict__ id: 4366423552, size:  232, len:  18
attr:  17  ||  o id: 4364598768  ||  __dict__ id: 4366429440, size:  232, len:  17
attr:  16  ||  o id: 4364598768  ||  __dict__ id: 4366285760, size:  232, len:  16
attr:  15  ||  o id: 4364598768  ||  __dict__ id: 4366423552, size:  232, len:  15
attr:  14  ||  o id: 4364598768  ||  __dict__ id: 4366422016, size:  232, len:  14
attr:  13  ||  o id: 4364598768  ||  __dict__ id: 4366419648, size:  232, len:  13
attr:  12  ||  o id: 4364598768  ||  __dict__ id: 4366431040, size:  232, len:  12
attr:  11  ||  o id: 4364598768  ||  __dict__ id: 4366419840, size:  232, len:  11
attr:  10  ||  o id: 4364598576  ||  __dict__ id: 4366421056, size:  232, len:  10
attr:   9  ||  o id: 4364598576  ||  __dict__ id: 4366419840, size:  232, len:   9
attr:   8  ||  o id: 4364598768  ||  __dict__ id: 4366418368, size:  232, len:   8
attr:   7  ||  o id: 4364598576  ||  __dict__ id: 4366420352, size:  232, len:   7
attr:   6  ||  o id: 4364598768  ||  __dict__ id: 4366422016, size:  232, len:   6
attr:   5  ||  o id: 4364598576  ||  __dict__ id: 4366429568, size:  232, len:   5
attr:   4  ||  o id: 4364598672  ||  __dict__ id: 4366431680, size:  232, len:   4
attr:   3  ||  o id: 4364599200  ||  __dict__ id: 4365801920, size:  232, len:   3
attr:   2  ||  o id: 4307971440  ||  __dict__ id: 4366281472, size:  232, len:   2
attr:   1  ||  o id: 4364598384  ||  __dict__ id: 4365401920, size:  232, len:   1
attr:   0  ||  o id: 4364599200  ||  __dict__ id: 4365013376, size:  232, len:   0
```

Ok, I gave up. I come to here to ask:

- Even though I call `gc.collect()`, the memory sizes of `__dict__` through the loops are still 232. Python some how caches the previous allocation size. How do I correct this cache issue? This is buggy for my code, because I create lots of object from the same Class, and I want to inspect the memory sizes. Right now, the results depend on the previously executed code (cache?).
- After calling `gc.collect()`, the `o id` and `__dict__ id` was ALMOST changed in the `for-loop`, but some `id` are the same with next loop. Was that normal? Are those objects released and re-allocated memory for each loop?

---

PS. I'm using macOS 12.3 (arm64 M1 Max) with Python 3.10.4. I'm not sure whether it's about the execution environment.